# restricting user to like a post more than once

Tags: python, django

I have a code that allows user to like the post but I realized the user can like the post more than once which I don't want. How do I restrict this?

my code

```
@login_required
def like_post(request, pk):
    if pk:
        liked_post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
        count = liked_post.likes
        count += 1
        liked_post.likes = count
        liked_post.save()


    return redirect('/community/post/%s' %liked_post.id)
```

what I tried

adding something like this....but not sure

```
if post.likes.filter(id=user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(user)
    else:
        post.likes.add(user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `unique_together` meta class option. This would raise a validation error which you could pass over if you didn't want to report an error.

In your Likes model (if you have one) include something like the following:

```
class Meta():
    unique_together = ('id', 'user')
```

Or add a '`liked_by`' attribute to Post as a `many to many field` to users which should manage the `uniqueness` stuff for you. The relationship can only exist once. You could use `Post.liked_by.count()` to get the number of likes, but I'd have no issue seeing the like count as its own attribute.